# How to check browser compatibility using java

Tags: java, browser

I'm writing an application in which a part is to check a webpage whether its compatible with 3 browsers (Chrome,Firefox,IE) using JAVA. Is there any ways to do it? Is there any plug-in?

Comment: What is stopping you from checking 'User-Agent' header?

Comment: `request.getHeader("user-agent");`

Comment: @Aboodz : Is that used to get information about the browser? Correct me if im wrong

Comment: @WarFox that is used to get details about the browser or os. Isn't it?

Comment: User-Agent header from modern browsers/clients will have many information like Browser version, rendering engine version, OS version etc.

Comment: What kind of compatibility are you looking for?

Comment: @WarFox I want to check whether the webpage can be loaded using that brower.... Its an automated system and as a small part i would like to check whether the web page i give will be able to load....

Comment: You want to check if a page can be loaded in a particular browser or not? Selenium could be of use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104171/discussion-between-vithushan-and-warfox).